# Opacity Transition not working in Firefox and IE (and others?)

Tags: html, css, opacity, transition

For my own website I'm showing the visitors a couple pictures. These pictures should be on an `opacity: 0.7;` then when hovering over them using `transition: opacity 0.50s ease-in-out;` the images should go to 100% visibility. The code under this paragraph shows how I got it working for Chrome. But even though it's working in Chrome, it won't work in browsers like Firefox and Internet Explorer.. Can you please help me on finding out what part of the code is wrong? I've already added all cross-browser opacity support I could think of!

```
.image.full2 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-opacity: 0.7;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.50s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.50s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.50s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.50s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.50s ease-in-out;
}

.image.full2:hover {
    -webkit-opacity: 1.0;
    -moz-opacity: 1.0;
    opactiy: 1.0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -khtml-opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

no need to define `-webkit-` or `-moz-` because almost the new browser support `opacity` property. but about IE8 or earlier version u should use `filter:alpha(opacity= x );` that x should be 0 to 100 %. maybe it help u... :)

```
.image.full2 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    opacity:0.7;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.50s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.50s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.50s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.50s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.50s ease-in-out;
}

.image.full2:hover {
    opacity:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/DcSnZ/1/

**Source:** http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Comment: This didn't help so far. All it did was disable the transition effect on Chrome too..

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
.image.full2 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.image.full2:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Same story as for Amin: This stopped the images in Chrome from transitioning too! Could it be that a js I'm running is disabling the effect of the transitioning on my site..?